# Pandas: Outer join with a specified range of difference between the keys

Tags: python, pandas, outer-join

I want to perform outer join on two data frames where the keys are `id: int` and `date: pd.Timestamp` objects. On top of that, I want the keys to be considered as equal if the `ids` are the same (the normal behaviour) and the dates are either equal (the normal behaviour) or the difference between the dates is maximum 30 days. Then, when the outer join is performed, the `date` from the right data frame should be taken. An example is included below:

```
left = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3], "date": [pd.Timestamp(2002, 3, 25), pd.Timestamp(2003, 4, 4), pd.Timestamp(2004, 6, 6)], "val_3": [77, 88, 11]})

right = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3], "date": [pd.Timestamp(2002, 3, 10), pd.Timestamp(2003, 4, 27), pd.Timestamp(2004, 5, 5)], "val_1": [99, 66, 33], "val_2": [101, 102, 103]})
```

And the result after the join should be:

```
result = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2, 3, 3], "date": [pd.Timestamp(2002, 3, 10), pd.Timestamp(2003, 4, 27), pd.Timestamp(2004, 6, 6), pd.Timestamp(2004, 5, 5)], "val_3": [77, 88, 11, np.nan], "val_1": [99, 66, np.nan, 33], "val_2": [101, 102, np.nan, 103]})
```

Looking forward to your answers!

Comment: What should happen if 2 dates in the right frame fall within 30 days of one date in the left frame for the same id? Should we get 2 rows for the date in the left frame, or do we take only the first or last date within that 30 day window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `merge` on `'id'` and then split the `DataFrame` as needed if the date doesn't fall within 30 days

```
import pandas as pd

# Rename so it's easier to split columns later
left = left.rename(columns={'date': 'date_l'})

m = left.merge(right, on='id', how='outer')
mask = m.date >= m.date_l - pd.Timedelta(days=30)

pd.concat([
    m[mask].drop(columns='date_l'),
    m.loc[~mask, left.columns].rename(columns={'date_l': 'date'}),
    m.loc[~mask, right.columns]], 
    ignore_index=True, sort=False)
```

#### Output:

```
   id  val_3       date  val_1  val_2
0   1   77.0 2002-03-10   99.0  101.0
1   2   88.0 2003-04-27   66.0  102.0
2   3   11.0 2004-06-06    NaN    NaN
3   3    NaN 2004-05-05   33.0  103.0
```

Comment: Although I concluded that my use-case is a lot more complex, this answer achieves what I said i want so I will mark it as correct.